# Reorder integer except for value 0 with sql

Tags: sql, mysql, database

I'm trying to get an ordered list of rows out of my MYSQL database table based upon an integer value 'place'.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
ORDER BY place;
```

This works okay, except that all rows with value place=0 should appear at the end of the table.

So if my table is:

```
name place
---- -----
John 1
Do   2
Eric 0
Pete 2
```

it should become:

```
name place
---- -----
John 1
Do   2
Pete 2
Eric 0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
ORDER BY place>0 DESC, place
```

is a solution without `CASE`

Comment: I like this solution as it's small and looks okay. Unless it's less efficient I keep this accepted.

Comment: or just `ORDER BY place=0, place`

Answer (score 6):

```
order by case when place = 0 then 1 else 0 end asc, place asc
```

that way you get all the non-zeroes ordered first.

Comment: Never seen the CASE construction before (but then, I got my SQL classes in the early nineties). Due to simpleness I prefer the @True Soft one.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
ORDER BY CASE place WHEN 0 THEN 9999 ELSE place END
```

This approach implies that we known that 9999 (or some other value) is bigger than all possible values in the place column.

Alternatively we can sort by two values as in:

```
   ORDER BY CASE place WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE -1 END, place
```

Comment: Thanks, the 9999 tricks was something I thought of myself, just didn't know you could change the evaluated sorting criteria of order. If a duplicate ordering list would have a high performance penalty this would be my first next choice.